# Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I have this equation $y^2 -2y = x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4$

How to solve this for $y$ in terms of $x$, because we have also the term $-2y$ on the left side?

Comment: This looks like a quadratic equation in $y$, then ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Very quick, and dirty solution*

$$y^2 -2y = x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4$$

$$y^2 -2y - \left(x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4\right) = 0$$

Let $c=x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4$

Thus, $$y^2-2y-c=0$$

is a quadratic in $y$, apply the quadratic formula.

---

$$y=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+4c}}{2}$$

$$y=1\pm\sqrt{c+1} = 1\pm\sqrt{x^3+2x^2+2x+5}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$y^2 -2y = x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4 \Rightarrow $$ $$y^2-2y+1-1=x^3+2x^2+2x+4 \Rightarrow$$ $$ (y-1)^2-1=x^3+2x^2+2x+4 \Rightarrow$$ $$ (y-1)^2=x^3+2x^2+2x+5 \Rightarrow $$ $$\sqrt{(y-1)^2}=\sqrt{x^3+2x^2+2x+5} $$

Answer (score 1):

This is only completing the square to the term: $Cy^2+Dy$. You can do it by using this:
$$Cy^2+Dy=C\left(y^2+\dfrac{D}{C}y\right)=C\left(y+\dfrac{D}{2C}\right)^2-C\left(\dfrac{D}{2C}\right)^2.\tag1$$
Using equation $(1)$, we complete the square the term: $y^2-2y$. We obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\color{red}{y^2-2y}&=1\left(y^2+\dfrac{(-2)}{(1)}y\right)\\
&=1\left(y+\dfrac{(-2)}{2(1)}\right)^2-1\left(\dfrac{(-2)}{2(1)}\right)^2\\
&=(y-1)^2-(-1)^2\\
&=\color{blue}{(y-1)^2-1}.\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Now, plug in $(2)$ into your equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\color{red}{y^2 -2y} &= x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4\\
\color{blue}{(y-1)^2-1}&=x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4\\
\color{blue}{(y-1)^2-1}\color{red}{+1}&=x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 4\color{red}{+1}\\
(y-1)^2&=x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 5\\
y-1&=\pm\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 5}\\
\Large\color{blue}y&=\Large\color{blue}{1\pm\sqrt{x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 5}}.
\end{align}
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$